# How does a spaceport differ from a launch pad?

Tags: launch, rockets, launchpad

How does a space port differ from a launch pad in construction and what makes them different?

Comment: The same way an airport differs from a runaway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Space port usually means cosmodrome: that is a framework of buildings and technical infrastructure dedicated to launching rockets into the space. A launch pad is part of the technical infrastructure.

So launch pad and space port are not 2 things of the same category, but rather a launch pad is part of a space port. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceport) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_pad).